# Searching for objects in the call stack when using the browser

Tags: r, debugging

When debugging functions calling other functions in many levels using the browser, it is often hard to know what level to enter on for inspecting a particular variable. It is cryptic when the functions contain `apply`, `sapply`, `lapply` calls producing intermediate levels. Is there a way to search for a variable by name on all levels of the stack?

Let's say I have the functions below, producing an error in `f3`. I would assume that when entering on level 5 I should be able to list the contents of any environment above the one I am currently in, using the `pos` or `envir` argument in some way, but I can't figure out how. How can I for instance look for `v2`?

```
f1 <- function(){
    v1 <- 1
    sapply(1:3, f2)
}
f2 <- function(...){
    v2 <- 2
    f3()
}
f3 <- function(){
    v3 <- 3
    stop("Oh no!")
}
> options(error=recover)
> f1()

Error in f3() : Oh no!

Enter a frame number, or 0 to exit

1: f1()
2: #3: sapply(1:3, f2)
3: lapply(X = X, FUN = FUN, ...)
4: FUN(1:3[[1]], ...)
5: #3: f3()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You obtain the callstack in a `list` with `sys.frames`. In this case, if you call `sys.frames` after the `browser` starts, you'll get a `list` of length 9. Frames 6-9 include the call that raised the error and the calls involved in starting the `browser` (you can see this by calling `sys.calls`). The first five frames are the ones displayed in the call stack that `recover` prints. Once the `browser` starts, you can look at the namespace of each level of the callstack in your example with

```
lapply(sys.frames()[1:5], ls)
```

or search for the frame containing the variable with

```
which(sapply(sys.frames(), function(frame) 'v2' %in% ls(frame)))
```